# Finding the perimeter of a simplex

Tags: computational-geometry

I hope this question is close enough to CS to be posted here. I need to write a method that will compute the perimeter of a simplex
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex in any dimension given only the coordinates of its vertices. Is such a function even possible? I have tried going for it, but ended up with loads of nested loops and nothing functional. Right now I have a class named Point and a class named Simplex which constructs a Simplex from an array of these points. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't all of the vertices edge-connected in a simplex? If so, have you considered just summing the distances of each of the vertices to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, my question was badly formulated, I had only coordinates of points not the vertices themselves, I have calculated the perimeter using the euclidean distance formula.